# Confusing how Laravel passport API security works

Tags: laravel, api, security, laravel-passport

Client sends username and password to the server.

Server then checks if this user is authenticated.

If yes, the server returns an access token for the client...

Then user can use this access token to access protected resources...

The advantage here, is that we are not sending user info via API calls, and the access token will not last for long time, so hackers won't be able to find out user authentication info (user name and password), and if he finds out, the access token won't last long enough to do anything with it.

That's how I understand Laravel passport API security.

The confusing thing here, is that on first API call, user has to send user name and password, so hacker still have big chance to find out user info!!!

I know that there is something wrong with my understanding, and that's why I get  confused, any explanation would be very appreciated.

Comment: using https decrease the chance of getting hacked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There must be a way to prove your identity to authorization server, and one way is to provide **username** and **password**. The way you're gonna achieve communication between authorization server and your client application is totally up to you as long as it uses HTTP. As stated in [RFC-6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749):

> This specification is designed for use with HTTP ([RFC2616]).  The
> use of OAuth over any protocol other than HTTP is out of scope.

Of course it's always advised to use HTTPS whenever possible. Just because HTTP is mentioned in document, doesn't mean HTTPS cannot be used because HTTPS is just encrypted version of HTTP.

Other thing I wanted to mention is that you don't need to provide **username** and **password**, there are several grant types where you can, for example, instead of **username** and **password** you can provide **client_id** and **client_secret** which is used in **Client Credentials** grant type.

If you are new to this I believe this all is little bit confusing for you. To summarize the purpose of OAuth2 to you (as far as I get it), is:

- To separate role of the client (which can be browser, mobile etc.) from the resource owner (usually the owner of account). Why? Because if there is no separation, the client has access to user's sensitive data.
- Imagine that the first point is secure enough for communication. But what happens if someone gets their hands on the session you have? They have access to all! This is why OAuth introduces scopes, where depending on the scope user has with provided **access token** has limited access to resources. Scope can be read, write, share etc. - this implementation is up to developer. So if someone gets their hands on your **access token**, because of scope they only have a limited access to resource.

These are one of my reasons, while [RFC-6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) has better explanation:

- Third-party applications are required to store the resource
  owner's credentials for future use, typically a password in
  clear-text.
- Servers are required to support password authentication, despite
  the security weaknesses inherent in passwords.
- Third-party applications gain overly broad access to the resource
  owner's protected resources, leaving resource owners without any
  ability to restrict duration or access to a limited subset of
  resources.
- Resource owners cannot revoke access to an individual third party
  without revoking access to all third parties, and must do so by
  changing the third party's password.
- Compromise of any third-party application results in compromise of
  the end-user's password and all of the data protected by that
  password.

To learn more about OAuth2, it's grant types and purposes, I recommend you to read this:

1. [An Introduction to OAuth 2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2)
2. Mentioned [RFC-6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749), even though it can be difficult to read because of technical writing.

Hope I clarified at least a small piece of blur.

Comment: Yes you clearified a good piece of blur, but please help me to find out if I correctly understood you. [instead of username and password you can provide client_id and client_secret ]

But still the hacker can get these data, and if he got them he can request an access token for him!!!

[So if someone gets their hands on your access token, because of scope they only have a limited access to resource.]

But if he gets his hands on the owner access token, then he can make real damage!!!

Comment: What I can conclude from your answer is the following
 When user send first request into server to get an access token, oAuth is not useful to protect me from hackers and introders, and so I should use https with first request to secure it! and I can skip using https in the rest request to get better performance, as they will be secured by aouth.

I'm just want to make sure that I get understood your explannation, so kindly just tell me if my conclusion is true or not...

Comment: Yup, that's quite bit. OAuth is not there for secure communication, that role goes up to HTTPS, OAuth is just another way to authenticate users. You can have form based authentication and it's still not secured if HTTPS is not used.

Comment: Main reason why OAuth is introduced is because at some point, there was a need that one application (web app, mobile app, desktop app, etc), need to access resource from domain which does not belong to the app. There was a need to separate resource owner from the client which needs to process your data, and OAuth solved that.

Comment: To make things clear, lets take facebook for example. There are third party websites where they want to be able to have account on their site using facebook (login with facebook option). After using that option you can clearly see that they accessed you profile data because you've confirmed that, you gave scope.

In this scenario, those third party websites are clients which wants to access resource from facebook, but they has to be distinguished from resource owner, because they are not, so they have limited access due to the scope.