# Laravel 5.5 Passport client_secret and Vue JS Auth

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Good Day everyone,

I'm learning Laravel Passport and Vue.JS(standalone) at the same time.
I'm using `Password Grant Token` to authenticate the user.

I encounter this issue that the `secret_key` must be always hidden.

I have this `Login Component` in my vuejs where I need to add the `client_secret` as parameter to get access token. However, since VUEJS is a javascript framework. there's a way that someone can see the `client_secret` on the minified build file.

my question is that, is it just normal? is there a way to conceal the `client_secret`?

at first I don't mind the issue since I have implemented `CORS` on laravel where I can only select the `allowedOrigins`. My thinking is that it doesn't matter if they know the secret key as long as I can filter the `allowedOrigins`.

Here's my code in VUEJS

```
login(){
        this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
          if (result) {
              var data = {
                client_id: 3,
                client_secret: 'client-secret key',
                grant_type: 'password',
                username: this.inputs.email,
                password: this.inputs.password
            }
            this.$http.post("oauth/token", data).then(response => {
                this.$auth.setToken(response.body.access_token, response.body.expires_in + Date.now());
                bus.$emit('reload');
                this.$router.push('/');
            })
          }
        });
      }
```

Any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused with this too hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669468/confusing-how-laravel-passport-api-security-works

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Passport has a [built in way](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript) of allowing you to consume your own API with a Javascript application. It provides a simple middleware which you can add to your `web` middleware group (which you'll find in `App\Http\Kernel`):

```
'web' => [
    // Other middleware...
    \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
],
```

Laravel will check to see if you have a logged in user (via the standard cookie/session guard) and if so it will generate JWT for you and store it in a cookie. It will also check for this cookie's presence and validate it when you make requests to your API so you no longer need to pass an access token.

One thing to note however, is that you will need to ensure that you continue to pass your CSRF tokens with your requests (assuming you have CSRF protection turned on). If you're using Axios with Vue, you can make sure this happens very easily with the following:

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
};
```

With this approach you don't need to worry about access tokens at all or expose a `client_id` and `secret` to the client.

Comment: This is great but sometimes you just have a separate SPA and this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and found an interesting solution.
You can add a custom endpoint on the backend and make the request from there.

All you have to do is to:

First, create a route in the api.php file `Route::post('/login', 'AuthController@login');`

Then, create the AuthController and login function associated with that route `php artisan make:controller AuthController`

Finally, install Guzzle, the HTTP client that will allow you to make a request from PHP `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle` and make the request from the login function

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

    try {

        $response = $http->post('http://example.test/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => 2,
                'client_secret' => 'your_client_secret',
                'username' => $request->username,
                'password' => $request->password,
            ]
        ]);

        return $response->getBody();

    } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {

        if($e->getCode() == 400)
        {
            return response()->json('Invalid Request, Please enter email or password.', $e->getCode());
        }
        else if($e->getCode() == 401)
        {
            return response()->json('Your credentials are incorrect. Please try again', $e->getCode());
        }

        return response()->json('Something went wrong on the server.', $e->getCode());

    }
}
```

Now, the vue.js front end app juste needs to send a post request to `http://example.test/login` with the username and password to get back the `access_token` without knowing the `client_secret` since it is abstracted to the backend.

[Here is the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGh0cKEVXPI&index=9&list=PLEhEHUEU3x5q-xB1On4CsLPts0-rZ9oos) that explains it and implements it really well.

And [a presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZbtNGdVDi4) about some theory and how you can store and send the token from the vue.js app once you retrieve the token.

Hope this helps.