# Request token on API using Laravel Passport

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-passport

I am creating a login feature using Laravel Passport. Can I use `auth()->id()` without sending the bearer token on the Authorization header? If I put the token on header everyone can see it on the browser `Network` and it is not safe what is the other option?

This is my login controller API

```
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $data = [
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password
        ];

        if (auth()->attempt($data)) {
            $token = auth()->user()->createToken('WebAppToken')->accessToken;
            return response()->json([
                'token' => $token
            ], 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }
    }
```

This is my userInfo controller API

```
    public function userInfo()
    {
        $user = User::where('id', auth()->id())->first();

        return response()->json([
            'user' => $user
        ], 200);
    }
```

Comment: refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669468/confusing-how-laravel-passport-api-security-works

Answer (score 0):

Sending the token via headers is the convenient way. The token will be viewable on the browser network. Additional security measures such as setting a shorter life span of the token may help. On logout, correctly destroy the token and it will be blacklisted - hence, won't be granted access to anyone holding it.

Answer (score 0):

Without providing the bearer token on the Authorization header, we cannot utilise auth()->id(), and if we pass it on the request header, it will also be visible on the browser network. I believe you should reduce the token's lifespan.